# PIL: Convert Bytearray to Image

Tags: python, arrays, image, byte, python-imaging-library

I am trying to verify a bytearray with `Image.open` and `Image.verify()` without writing it to disk first and then open it with `im = Image.open()`. I looked at the `.readfrombuffer()` and `.readfromstring()` method, but there I need the size of the image (which I could only get when converting the bytestream to an image).

My Read-Function looks like this:

```
def readimage(path):
    bytes = bytearray()
    count = os.stat(path).st_size / 2
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        print "file opened"
        bytes = array('h')
        bytes.fromfile(f, count)
    return bytes
```

Then as a basic test I try to convert the bytearray to an image:

```
bytes = readimage(path+extension)
im = Image.open(StringIO(bytes))
im.save(savepath)
```

If someone knows what I am doing wrong or if there is a more elegant way to convert those bytes into an image that'd really help me.

P.S.: I thought I need the bytearray because I do manipulations on the bytes (glitch them images). This did work, but I wanted to do it without writing it to disk and then opening the imagefile from the disk again to check if it is broken or not.

Edit: All it gives me is a `IOError: cannot identify image file`

Comment: Why don't you read the image into numpy array?

Comment: @ViktorKerkez because I want to manipulate the Bytes of the images. I have working code for the Manipulation part, but now I want to verify the output image is actually not totally broken. So I _have_ to work with bytearrays

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you manipulate with `bytearrays`, then you have to use `io.BytesIO`. Also you can read a file directly to a `bytearray`.

```
import os
import io
import PIL.Image as Image

from array import array

def readimage(path):
    count = os.stat(path).st_size / 2
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return bytearray(f.read())

image_bytes = readimage(path+extension)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
image.save(savepath)
```

Comment: Why do you half the st_size?  And why declare `count` at all?

Comment: @jdborg Because the OP did the same thing in his question. :) I just copy/pasted the code and fixed the error.

Comment: Also might be worth pointing out that `bytes` is a reserved word in Python