# python convert bytes to image

Tags: python, image, byte

I receive a bytes, which is converted from an image from Android client, how can I convert it to image on Python?
I use these code:

```
img = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
img.show()
img.save('D:\\1.jpg')
```

but I can only get an incomplete image like:

[image]

The image on the right is what I'm trying to send to Python, and the left is what I get. How can I solve this?

PS:`data` is complete because I save the image completely by using Eclipse.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `data` is complete and the correct length?

Comment: This answer might help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491416/pil-convert-bytearray-to-image]

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it is complete because I save the image completely by using Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I have already solve the problem.I made a stupid mistake that the `buffersize` I set for `socket.recv` is too short.
I set a longer `buffersize` like 100000000, and saving the image is easy like:

```
 f = open('D:\\2.jpg', 'wb')
 f.write(data)
 f.close()
```