# How to convert bytes from string to image in python?

Tags: python, image, python-3.7

I have this byte object in string format inside a `.txt`file and I'm lost on how to convert it back into byte object, like `img=b'\x00\x00\x00'` so that I can write it back into an image.

The image is supposed to be a black square when back to image format.

```py
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xdd\x00\x00\x00\xdd\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00?\xc4w\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x01\xc7o\xa8d\x00\x00\x00!tEXtCreation Time\x002019:07:22 19:10:08\xa0\x9d\xf4\xb4\x00\x00\x02\x80IDATx^\xed\xd3\xb1\r\xc00\x00\xc30\xa7\xff\xff\xdcf\xe8\r\x9aH\xc0\xf0\x05:\xdb\xde; \xf2\xfc\x0fDD\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x10\x13\x1d\xc4D\x071\xd1ALt\x90\xda>\xddB\x02\xb9L3W\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

Opening the file `.txt` file with the byte object

```
file=open('filename.txt','r').read()
```

I tried this, but the `file` is in a string format

```py
with open('new_pic.png','wb')as img:
    img.write(file)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIL: Convert Bytearray to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491416/pil-convert-bytearray-to-image)

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I looked into the link and I don't think it's a duplicate because mine is not a bytearray and I'm trying to convert in from a string to a byte format.

Answer (score 8):

You should be reading the file as binary (`"rb"`).

```
file = open('filename.txt', 'rb').read()
print(type(file))  # <class 'bytes'>
print(file)        # b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\x06\x0

with open("image.png", "wb") as img:
    img.write(file)
```

Now, I don't know why you have image bytes stored in a text file, but a better implementation would be to use image-related modules like [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) to read-write image files:

```
from PIL import Image

file = Image.open("input.png")
file.save("output.png")
```