# Django websockets image upload binary get extension

Tags: django, image, file-upload, websocket

I am trying to send image via javascript websockets as binary data

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/message/');

var file = document.getElementById('ImageUpload').files[0];
console.log(file)
ws.binaryType = "blob";
ws.send(file)
```

Using Django channels I am receiving the binary data

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class Consumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        .....
        .....
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        if bytes_data:
            # doing some stuffs
```

How can get the extension(.jpg/.png) of the image file form the binary data which I receive via websocket, can you pleas guide me some suggestion for this, it will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't know the exact file extension unless you include it in the message.
Otherwise, you could read the first 2 KiB of the file and use `python-magic` (or similar) to infer the [MIME type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image).

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your bytes_data to image by Pillow library in python.take a look at this link:
[PIL: Convert Bytearray to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491416/pil-convert-bytearray-to-image)