# How do I convert an bytes image from BytesIO to a PIL image in python?

Tags: python, image, io, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I converted to bytes using the method below:

```py
import io
from PIL import Image

def image_to_byte_array(image:Image):
    imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(imgByteArr, format=image.format)
    imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
    return imgByteArr
```

Here is how I called the above method PIL Image.read()  to covert it to bytes

```py
im = Image.read("mam.JPG")
im_bytes = image_to_byte_array(im)
```

Now I want to reverse the process and convert the image back to a PIL Image. How do I do this ?

Comment: You can use the following syntax: `image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(im_bytes))`. See: [PIL: Convert Bytearray to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491416/pil-convert-bytearray-to-image)

Comment: Thank you. I got it.